# mySql workbench error: could not open error log file no such file or directory

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

[image: Buenas, estoy haciendo mi proyecto pero a la hora de iniciar el server me tira esto, y de ahi se congela y no me deja avanzar :( alguien sabe alguna solución? tengo desde ayer intentandolo solucionar pero no he podido] Buenas, estoy haciendo mi proyecto pero a la hora de iniciar el server me tira esto, y de ahi se congela y no me deja avanzar :( alguien sabe alguna solución? tengo desde ayer intentandolo solucionar pero no he podido

Answer (score 0):

|| Solución ||

La única forma es volviéndolo a instalar